# Javascript sort an array by biggest and lowest number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need help with the sorting as i am totally confused what to do. This is the example:

[1, 65, 3, 52, 48, 63, 31, -3, 18, 56] to [-3, 65, 1, 63, 3, 56, 18, 52, 31, 48].
The first element has to be the smallest, the second to be biggest, the third to be the second smallest element, the fourth to be the second biggest element.

What i have tried is:

```js
function solve(arr) {
  var lowestNum = [...arr].sort((a,b) => a-b);
  let biggestNum = [...arr].sort((a,b) => b-a);
  let nums = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (nums.length !== arr.length) {
    nums.push(lowestNum.shift()); lowestNum.pop();
    nums.push(biggestNum.shift()); biggestNum.pop();
    i++;
  }
  return nums;
}
console.log(solve([1, 65, 3, 52, 48, 63, 31, -3, 18, 56]));
```

However, that is not the way as my exercise requires me to sort.

Comment: Just a little tip: formatted code is more likely to get help

Comment: I'm confused. The output matches your requested output.

Comment: Looks working so I'm voting to close. As an aside, the time complexity could be reduced by using counters instead of `shift()` which is O(n).

Comment: I will copy-paste the condition: Write a function that sorts an array of numbers so that the first element is the smallest one, the second is the biggest one, the third is the second smallest one, the fourth is the second biggest one and so on. 
Return the resulting array.

What i've done works but it is not the way as it is not accepted.
@Pytth My bad. Will look more into formatting in the future.

Comment: Check `rosetta code` for shorting algorithms. https://rosettacode.org

Answer (score 0):

This isnt the most elegant solution, but:

```js
let a = [11, 2, 3, -22, 41];
function bigSmallSorter(arr) {
    // Sort a copy of the passed in array from least to most.
    let sortedArr = [...arr.sort((n, k) => n - k)];
    let newArr = [];
    let flip = true;

    for( let i of arr ) {
        let temp = flip 
            // Take first element of the sorted array
            ? sortedArr.shift()

            // Take the last element of the sorted array
            : sortedArr.pop();

        // Add the newest value to the value that is ultimately returned
        newArr.push(temp);

        // Flip this so the next iteration takes from the other
        // end of the array
        flip = !flip;
    }
    
    // Profit
    return newArr;
}


console.log(bigSmallSorter(a))

//>[ -22, 41, 2, 11, 3 ]
```

And an version of the method without comments:

```js
let a = [11, 2, 3, -22, 41];

function bigSmallSorter(arr) {
  let sortedArr = [...arr.sort((n, k) => n - k)]
  let newArr = [];
  let flip = true;

  for( let i of arr ) {
      let temp = flip 
          ? sortedArr.shift()
          : sortedArr.pop()
      newArr.push(temp)
      flip = !flip;
  }

  return newArr;
}

console.log(bigSmallSorter(a))
```